# magento 2 how to get product id from admin

Tags: magento2

In my requirement, I need product id from the admin product edit page on how to achieve this in Magento 2.
 I have tried 
$productId = $this->request->getParam('id'); 
but it is empty

> Model File:-

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Collection;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'sku';

    protected $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;


    /**
     * Define resource model.
     */
    const YOUR_TABLE = 'custom_table';

    protected $helper; public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->helper = $helper;

        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
    }



    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Post', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $area = $this->helper->getArea();

        if ($area == 'adminhtml') {

             $redirectUrl = $this->helper->getCurrentProduct();
             $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
             $attributeUrl = explode("/", $redirectUrl);
             $productId =  '23';
             $product = $this->helper->getLoadProduct($productId);
             $sku = $product->getSku();
             $customtag = $product->getCustomtags();
             $customtagsarr = explode("|",$customtag);
             $customvalues = "'" . implode ( "', '", $customtagsarr ) . "'";
            $this->getSelect()->orwhere("main_table.customtags IN($customvalues)");
        } else {
            $this->getSelect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is create simple custom module and Try some code :-

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
?>
```

**OR**

Add bellow code in your block file.

for example `app/code/yourvendor/yourmodulename/Block/CustomBlock.php`

```
<?php
namespace AR\CustomModule\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }   

}
?>
```

Printing current product data in your template (`custom.phtml`) file

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getSku() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getId() . '<br />';       
}
```

Hope this help

Thanks ...

Comment: I have tried but returns empty

Comment: Any idea to get product id from admin panel

Answer (score 0):

check this

add the below code into your template file.

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Add bellow code in your Block file.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class StockLeft extends Template
{
    private $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    protected function getCurrentProductID() 
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
    }

}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Hi i have tried but it also gives the empty value

Comment: $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');  instead of  $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

Comment: I need the product id in product edit page from backend i have tried the above ways but i did't get the value ....please give me any idea about this ,it will be helpful

Comment: i have tried the above way also 

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
           $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
         echo $param = $request->getParam('id');

Comment: you just add my code into the vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/templates/title.phtml and flush cache and check if it works or not for checking

Comment: If u give any idea how get product id from product edit page please share me

Comment: But i need the product id in my custom model file is it possible?

Comment: check i have update my answer

Comment: can you add your custom model code in  this question? so easy to help you

Comment: i have updated my model file please check

Comment: I have tried ur updated code but it shows
Call to a member function getId() on null  this error

Comment: try to get current product Id in your helper file and get in model

Comment: I have tried but it also shows empty

Comment: basically the problem is your custom model directly not connected to the product page

Comment: you can last try to when you click on particular edit product button then set product id in session and this session get in your model

Comment: okay i will try  lets update here thank you so much

Comment: Welcome @kanidhaya